# How to force an outputPanel refresh using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an apex:outputpanel that I'd like to force to refresh from within some jquery event handlers, rather than the extreme of a complete page refresh i.e. location.reload();

Any ideas on how from an event handler (not a button or link - is a 'drop' or 'click') I would perform the equivalent of a visualforce rerender="myoutputpanel" action would be most welcome!

Cheers All.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use a dummy `apex:actionFunction` to reRender any component on the page.

```
<script>
    jQuery('#someId').click(function(){
        // do your stuff
        ....
        // Now call action function 
        refreshMyPanel();
    });
</script>

<apex:actionFunction name="refreshMyPanel" reRender="MyPanel" />

<apex:outputPanel id="MyPanel">
    ....
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the visualforce `actionFunction` component, it's designed for this purpose.

> A component that provides support for invoking controller action
>   methods directly from JavaScript code using an AJAX request

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm

```
<script>window.setTimeout(sayHello,2000)</script>

<apex:form>
        <!-- Define the JavaScript function sayHello-->
        <apex:actionFunction name="sayHello" action="{!sayHello}" rerender="YOUR ID HERE" />
</apex:form>
```

Using `action={!NULL}` I believe you can simply force a refresh without needing a dummy method in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

To render `apex:outputpanel` by using using `javascript/jquery` **`actionFunctions`** are used.

Ex:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="doSomething" reRender="PanelToRefresh" action={!controllerMethod} />
```

Action Function tag is rendered as an ajax function in a visualforce page with name provided in `name` attribute to action function, So according to above code if this tag rendered on VF page it will have a function named `doSomething()` and you can call it in by any javascript function or jquery.

Fro ex:

```
function javascriptFunc()
{
   doSomething(); // or directly without wrapping in function
}
```

Basically `name` attrubute in `actionFunction` becomes ajax call function name when rendered and works exactly as `<apex:commandbuttom>` or `<apex:commandlink>` does and you can call it by adding `()` to it. In addition `actionFunction` allow variable assignments to controller which can be passed in rendered ajax call function as parameters.